# Adding individual Terraform arguments for each element in a list

Tags: loops, terraform, terraform0.12+, pagerduty

I'm using the [pagerduty_ruleset_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PagerDuty/pagerduty/latest/docs/resources/ruleset_rule) resource in combination with `count` to create multiple PagerDuty rules. Each rule is devised from a `count.index` of the `services` list of maps.

Variable definition - `services` list of maps (passed in as a `var.services`):

```
variable "services" {
  type        = list(object({ id = string, service_tags = list(string) }))
  description = "List of service IDs and tags to route events to"
}
```

Resource definition - `pagerduty_ruleset_rule`:

```
resource "pagerduty_ruleset_rule" "rule" {
  count = length(var.services)

  ruleset  = pagerduty_ruleset.custom_ruleset.id
  position = count.index
  disabled = false
  conditions {
    operator = "or"
    subconditions {
      operator = "contains"
      parameter {
        path  = "payload.group"
        value = "service:${var.services[count.index].service_tags[0]}"
      }
    }
    subconditions {
      operator = "contains"
      parameter {
        path  = "payload.group"
        value = "service:${var.services[count.index].service_tags[1]}"
      }
    }
  }
  actions {
    route {
      value = var.services[count.index].id
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how I have separate `subconditions` maps for each element in `service_tags`.

Is there a way to dynamically create `subconditions` maps based on the size of the `service_tags` list?

In the above code snippet, I assume that the size of the list is 2 (indexes `[0]` & `[1]`), but I'd like this to be dynamic - having the number of `subconditions` be equal to the size of the `service_tags` list.

Comment: Woudn't [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Marcin Good point. I started playing around with this but considering each `service` has it's own set of `service_tags`, I would need to convert the `count` to `for_each` then create a nested `for_each` inside of that for the `service_tags`. Is the nested for_each doable? I can't seem to get it working.